# Cross platform NavigationDrawer/SideMenu?

Tags: xamarin, navigation-drawer, side-menu

Architecture question: Are there components or a convention to follow to implement a cross platform navigation drawer / side menu? I've found platform specific implementations that aren't similar enough to be implemented consistently in a cross platform way. The MvvmCross iOSSupport library's Xamarin.Sidebar seems to be specific to iOS, as is the stock DrawerLayout on Android, but their implementations seem too different. Does a one size fits all solution exist, or will I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Xamarin.Forms, this is exactly how `MasterDetailPage` works. If you ask for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS the question isn't logically consistent - even if you could display an empty panel by some unified package there is no way that you could add controls to it as it has to be done completely separately (as there are no common controls) and the common package for this cannot be made.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the [MasterDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page)

> The Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage is a page that manages two related
>   pages of information – a master page that presents items, and a detail
>   page that presents details about items on the master page.

[image: Image Example]